# What timestamp format is this 20130218001203638?

Tags: timestamp

I am dealing with a dataset and I am unable to understand the format of this 16 digit timestamp. If it makes sense to anyone, please let me know. `20130218001203638`

Comment: Just as a guess all the digits are smushed together yearmonthdayhourminute.... 4 digit year 2 digit everything else (except possibly millisecond if it goes that far.)

Comment: I agree with Raystorm looks like 3 digits milliseconds at the end, otherwise standard ISO date format without delimiter

Comment: So you guys say it is YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMiS ?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what we're saying.

Comment: Okay, thanks folks, if there is any document to verify this, do post it below. Meanwhile I'll stick with this :) Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Link to any actual common timestamp format Documentation.
I came to my guess based on some of my own Java code. (I didn't come up with the format.)

I have a Date format class that leverages [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```java
/** @return a y2 date string of the passed in time to the millisecond
 *          Format: YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecondMillisecond
 */
public static String getY2MillisecondDate(GregorianCalendar today)
{
   return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS").format(today.getTime());
}
```

As you can see by the pasted function, my code calls it a **y2 millisecond** string.
The *other* y2 date format string my code uses is defined as `yyyyMMdd`.  I'd have to research to find out where the use of the "y2" format in my code originated.

**EDIT:**
I did some research the `yyyyMMdd` is called a "Year-2000 Format" and appears to be standardized in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as a "basic format". [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date)